# Plotting Problems on Matlab How could I draw?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to plot level curve of f(x,y) = y^4 - 2*x*y^2 + x^3 - x over [-5,4] x [-3,3], but I am stuck. This my code and how should I continue to it?

My Code:

```
x = linspace(-5, 4, 25);
y = linspace(-3, 3, 25);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
z = @(x,y) y.^4-2*x*y.^2+x^3-x;
Z = z(X,Y);
surf(X,Y,Z)
```

Comment: I think you should first explain what an isoquant curve is. Wiki tells me it is a concept in economics. The code you have attached plots a 3-D mesh (surf). What else would you like to plot?

Comment: @liorr: True, it is a concept in economics, but it is like a normal level curve and I should show gradients which are on this curve, but I couldn't although I tried it

Comment: Can you attach/link to an example showing what you want to do?

Comment: It should be like that ( it is different function, not same )

Comment: One more question: did you mean `z = @(x,y) y.^4-2*x*y.^2+x^3-x` or `z = @(x,y) y.^4-2.*x.*y.^2+x.^3-x` ? (note the dots between the product and exponent operators).

Comment: Then you most definitely mean the second one :) See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
clear

x = linspace(-5, 4, 25);
y = linspace(-3, 3, 25);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
z = @(x,y) y.^4-2.*x.*y.^2+x.^3-x;
Z = z(X,Y);

% Probing some line parallel to the x axis:
y_probe = 0;

% Probing a point to calculate the gradient in:
x_probe = -3;

% Getting all points for which x = x_probe:
z_probe = z(x, y_probe);
% Compute the gradient:
dx = gradient(x);
dz = gradient(z_probe);
dzdx = dz./dx;

clf
subplot(121)
surf(X,Y,Z)
hold on
plot3(x, ones(1,length(y)) .* y_probe, z_probe ,'r','linewidth',2)

subplot(122)
plot(x, z_probe,'r','linewidth',1)
hold on
xi = find(x > x_probe, 1);

plot(x, dzdx(xi) .* (x - x(xi)) + z_probe(xi),'k--','linewidth',1);
h = quiver(x(xi), z_probe(xi), -dx(xi), dz(xi),'k','LineWidth',2);

xlim([min(x) max(x)])
ylim([min(z_probe) max(z_probe)])
```

To get:
[image: Requested curve]

Comment: Sir.. I am so so sorry, I didn't understand what happened :S, I edited again. Thank you very much for your effort. God bless you